# Angular 5 Routes not working, Redirects to default

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular2-routing, angular-router

Well stuck in some issues with angular 5. Made an application, defined the routes but on fire of any url, it navigates to default(404 in my case). Please help me guys.
Here is my route structure.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'authentication',
    loadChildren: './authentication/authentication.module#AuthenticationModule',
}, {
    path: 'select-administration',
    loadChildren: './main/content/select-administration/select-administration.module#SelectAdministrationModule',
}, {
    path: 'apps',
    loadChildren: './main/main.module#FuseMainModule',
}, {
    path: 'administration',
    loadChildren: './main/content/administration/administration.module#AdministrationModule',
}, {
    path: 'profile',
    loadChildren: './main/content/user-profile/user-profile.module#UserProfileModule',
}, {
    path: '**',
    loadChildren: './main/content/404/error-404.module#Error404Module'
}
];
```

Here is my `app.module.ts` where i defined routes.

```
imports     : [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    SharedModule,
    FileUploadModule,
    NgbModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    ToastrModule.forRoot(),
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app module should have parent path along with load children. load them using RouterModule.forRoot. Then have separate feature module for authentication, user-profile etc. In the feature module have child path and load using RouterModule.forChild. There is a good article in this link.

https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/how-to-lazy-load-components-in-angular-4-in-three-steps/